# Unhandled exception at 0x012219c4 in SW-Serial.exe

Tags: c

i declare 2d dynamic array. when run program this error shown:
Unhandled exception at 0x012219c4 in SW-Serial.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xabababab.

the part of my program that error occured:

```
    double** SWArray;  
SWArray = (double**) malloc(lenA*sizeof(double*));  
for (int i = 0; i <= lenA; i++)  
    SWArray[i] = (double*) malloc(lenB*sizeof(double));  

for(int i=0;i<=lenA;i++){
    SWArray[0][i]=0;
}
for(int j=0;j<=lenB;j++){
    SWArray[j][0]=0;
}
```

[picture](http://i1353.photobucket.com/albums/q671/mahdimb/ad2_zps953af9f7.jpg) of this problem

Comment: You should check your loop limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lenA And lenB mixed up. It should be:

SWArray[i][0] and SWArray[0][j] in your loops.

And you loops should use < not <=

Comment: i should perform both these steps not only change <= to <. i perform these 2 steps together and its now work. thanks:-)

Answer (score 3):

Arrays start from 0 in C. Wherever you say `i <= lenA` it should be `i < lenA`. Same goes for `j` and `lenB`. Also, the second loop doesn't really make sense. Did you mean `lenB` instead of `lenA` ?

Answer (score 0):

Both the loops are indexing in the wrong dimension and also are accessing elements beyond the size for which memory is allocated. You should change `i<=` to `i<` in both the loops

The correct way should be:

```
for(int i=0;i<lenA;i++){
    SWArray[i][0]=0;
}
for(int j=0;j<lenB;j++){
    SWArray[0][j]=0;
}
```